# Multi jobs over local (IntelliJ) and Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have to build a way for my tests to work with multi jobs over any platform using IntelliJ and Jenkins

I have heard that I can do this with JUnit 5. I have not been able to find any references about this.

Can someone with experience in setting up multi jobs in Jenkins point me to some good references?

Answer (score 1):

You can check out [this](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin) **MultiJob** plugin for Jenkins. Or if its the same job you want to run in different configuration you can make use of Multi-configuration job type in Jenkins.

I have tried searching for JUnit5 supporting multi jobs scenario as specified didn't find any decent information on the same.

Comment: Bradz, Thanks.
At Jenkins as standalone is not hard to find with tests to run and how (by using pipelines ex.), but over the code, i would like to see a better way (maybe structure) for build code with an option to be able multi jobs at any platform. For example, basic command line if needed.